# Drawing many quads

Tags: c++, optimization, opengl, frame-rate

I'm making something similar to Minecraft Classic.
I already got terrain generator , but frame rate is very low !

I already optimized it , that's it's drawing only quads which can be visible.
I'm using glBegin(GL_QUADS) and glEnd() but only once, and a lot of glVertex3fv. I'm starting to learning this, so I don't want to use VBO etc. So what I can do ?

PS. I'm not using textures.

## edit

Picture
img580.imageshack.us/img580/5547/fpsx.jpg

## edit 2

In fact my pseudo optimization don't do anything at all ...

img143.imageshack.us/img143/9163/fps5.jpg

That's when everything is drawn , only 3 fps worse ... That's not good ...

But look there's much more glVertex... calls (almost 47 times more) but frame rate is similar , so maybe that's not a problem , so where is it ?

## edit 3

Also I will add information that there isn't any fps limit :

img339.imageshack.us/img339/4111/fps6.jpg

## it's probably all

Anyway, thanks for help. Now I'm going to learn how to use VBO (wish me good luck). After changing from Debug to Release there was small (or even not so small) improvement (over 100 fps - before 18). But it was only for 3x3 chunks (48x48 blocks), now when I increased it to 5x5 chunks (80x80 blocks) it's again 30-40 fps ...

http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/2321/fps7.jpg

Again thanks for help. Probably I will keep asking with VBO :)

Comment: How many glVertex3fv? Any other details? What else do you do?

Comment: Please wait a few minutes whilst I go fetch my psychic hat.

Comment: added picture with glVertex3fv calls

Comment: 14k vertex is nothing for modern graphical chips. Did you somehow triggered software rendering?

Comment: @VJo Uh, I don't know ... I'm also I'm surprised why I got so few fps ... (V-Sync is off)

Comment: You can't want to speed things up and then outright ban the use of VBOs. I understand that you are just learning, but when drawing huge bunches of vertices, sending them over the bus every frame is murder. Learn how to store the data in VRAM (via VBO).

Comment: @TheBuzzSawYes, I realize that I have to learn it, thanks. But I just changed from Debug to Release and I have over 100 fps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use VRAM buffers.

Optimizing the visible faces helps significantly, as does batching faces when drawing, but neither will have a really significant benefit when all faces are stored in system RAM and you're sending the verts one-by-one.

You need to create a VBO on the GPU and download the geometry to that whenever it changes. Render that each frame and it will be far more efficient.

Rough testing while writing a (non-Minecraft) voxel engine showed roughly a 50-80x gain when the cubes were organized into a small set of buffers on the GPU. That was over raw cubes stored on the GPU, going from immediate to buffers will be even greater.

There are some libraries and engines that may help you handle the buffers and underlying objects. Once you have the geometry generation algorithm, most engines will accept the created mesh for use in an object of some sort. For OpenGL in specific, the [Visualization Library](http://www.visualizationlibrary.com/jetcms/) may be of help.

Comment: I already tried to make it with glDrawElements but it's hard to draw so many quads with only one glDrawElements for me ...

Comment: During my playing around, I generated each 16x16x16 blocks of voxels into a buffer (primarily to do occlusion and frustrum culling, but it also simplifies this a bit). For a decent-size area, it came to about 340 buffers. For geometry that may change, you'll need some kind of chunk concept to avoid regenerating the entire buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you could optimize your series of quads into a trianglestrip instead you would probably see a significant increase.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip

Comment: Tristrips tend to be rather complicated to generate (and can often be slower than trilists). Drawing GL_QUADs is likely to map to one or the other anyway, it's calling glVertex thousands of times that is the issue.

Comment: changed form glBegin(GL_QUADS) to glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)

no improvement :/
http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/4797/fps2u.jpg

Comment: This is off course not completely true. It is true that the quads in broken into triangles, but the improvement from that will not be significant.